# EPPlus v4.5.0.2rc Asp.Net Core MVC 2.0 w/ .NET 4.7 platform - corrupt data

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, epplus

**Answer:**

Turns out the axios lib (ajax) needs to have the content type set to blob. **I checked other, older, code and did not have to do that but once I did it worked.

`axios.get(HS.Routes.Test.TestExcelDT(), { responseType: 'blob' })`

---

**Preface**:  I have been using EPPlus for several years with no problem in both ASP.NET Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC 5 but switching to the latest version of EPPlus (v4.5.0.2rc) on ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0 I get nothing that Excel can open.

**Error:**

See following Excel error images:

[image: 1st Excel Error]
[image: 2nd Excel Error]

#### Detail (updated)

**Log entries:**

```
02/09/2018 06:56:23 - Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost/CoreTest/Home/TestExcel  
02/09/2018 06:56:23 - Executing action method CoreTest.Controllers.HomeController.TestExcel (CoreTest) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
02/09/2018 06:56:24 - Executing FileResult, sending file as test_excel.xlsx
02/09/2018 06:56:24 - Executed action CoreTest.Controllers.HomeController.TestExcel (CoreTest) in 810.0491ms
02/09/2018 06:56:24 - Request finished in 836.474ms 200 application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

**In my .csproj we have to target .Net 4.7 instead of Net Core 2.0, does that make a difference?:**

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net47</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**(updated)** This is all of the source I am running for this simple test.  I changed my initial example to be as simple as possible and to remove external data call.  I also tried using a List (not shown) with same results**

**Controller**

```cs
public IActionResult TestExcel()
{
    const string XlsxContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

    var dt = new DataTable("Users");
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
    var rnd = new Random();
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var row = dt.NewRow();
        row["Name"] = $"User {i}";
        row["Age"] = rnd.Next(20, 100);
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Excel Test");
        worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, PrintHeaders: true);
        for (var col = 1; col < dt.Columns.Count + 1; col++)
        {
            worksheet.Column(col).AutoFit();
        }

        return File(package.GetAsByteArray(), XlsxContentType, "test_excel.xlsx");
    }
}
```

**Client Side**

This is my standard AJAX using axios lib, has worked for several years with EPPlus byte array:

```js
// WRONG => axios.get(HS.Routes.Home.TestExcel(), null)

axios.get(HS.Routes.Test.TestExcelDT(), { responseType: 'blob' })
.then(function (response)
{
    switch (response.status)
    {
        case 200:
            var fileName = "stores_excel.xlsx";
            var anchorDownload = document.createElement("a");
            anchorDownload.style = "display: none;";
            document.body.appendChild(anchorDownload);

            var blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" });
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            anchorDownload.href = url;
            anchorDownload.download = fileName;
            anchorDownload.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            document.body.removeChild(anchorDownload);
            break;
        default:
            console.error("Fatal Error running excel report: ", response.statusText);
            break;
    }
})
.catch(function (err)
{
    console.error(err.response.statusText);
});
```

**POINTS**

- I need to use AJAX to call the controller and get the data as we use common js libs across all apps
- I do not care how the binary data is built server side as long as it is valid and can be consumed as Blob data client side

**Any help would be welcome, thanks**

Comment: Does the error message provide a path to a log where you can check what elements of the document are corrupt? Is Excel able to repair it or is it completely corrupted?

Comment: It does not, just the message which is actually what Excel says when trying to open the file. Excel cannot repair it

Comment: Updated question: errors, log entries, source

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

Turns out the axios lib (ajax) needs to have the content type set to blob.  **I checked other, older, code and did not have to do that but once I did it worked.

`axios.get(HS.Routes.Test.TestExcelDT(), { responseType: 'blob' })`